# why DataType.EmailAddress converted link automatically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using a model with DataType.EmailAddress. I would like to modify the address link in the run time, however it already has email link automatically that prevents my modification.

```
@{
    var subject = "";
    if (Model.Name.Length > 30)
    {
        subject = Model.Name.Substring(0, 30) + "...";
    }
    else
    {
        subject = Model.Name;
    }
}
<a href="mailto:@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.email)?subject=Re: @subject">model => model.email</a>
```

But I got

```
<a href="mailto:&lt;a href=&quot;mailto:emailaddress&quot;&gt;emailaddress&lt;/a&gt;?subject=Re: subject"><a href="mailto:emailaddress">emailaddress</a></a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="mailto:&lt;a href=&quot;mailto:emailaddress&quot;&gt;emailaddress&lt;/a&gt;?subject=Re: subject">emailaddress</a>
```

Why the email address is converted into link form automatically? And how to stop it? I would like to keep the datatype to use validation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to print the value of the property: `@model.Email`.
`DisplayFor` is not what you want.

Also, you need to URL-encode the `subject` parameter, including the space after `Re:`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked as I expected. Only one more thing is the encoded subject contains '+' as a replacement of space. Any other way to show space as it is?